# Swap view content on button press

Tags: ios

One page in my application has a button where the user can change between two modes. The content of the page should be different depending on which mode is selected. In this case, it's not correct to push another view controller - the new UI components should be on the very same page.

However, I haven't found out how this can be done in iOS. I have seen Container Views (Which I couldn't get to appear on the screen) that seems to have other purpose (reusability). I guess I could also manually hide/show each of the UI components depending on the mode, but I want to know if there is a more effective way (Like Wrapping the content in a compund view and Hide/show only that).

Btw, I'm looking for a solution that uses Storyboards (or XIBs) as much as possible.

Comment: There are many different solutions for this, including Tab Bar controllers, hide/show views, child view controllers, etc. You'll need to narrow options a bit and come up with specific questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create view controllers for all your different views, get them from the storyboard when needed (after button press), add them as children to your main view controller with `addChildViewController` and add their view to your main view. You can animate that transition any way you like with `UIView animateWithDuration`.

When you are done with a view/view controller, remove the view and remove the view controller from its parent with `removeFromParentViewController`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a view controller, when user clicks button to change the mode, instead of push view controller, use flipping of view controller. below is the code that can be used instead of push

```
 UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
 UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"idVC"];

 vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
 [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This will flip the view controller, further, you can dismiss this view controller and continue with the normal app flow.